# Select to Block on Receving ENOSPC while write

Tags: c, select, fuse

My Application is continuously writing on a file through fuse. And whenever there is no space available in file my application should wait untill space is available.
So, basically my Complete System is like the following:
Top Layer: Application_1
Middle Layer: libfuse
Lower Layer: Application_2

Now, Application_1 is continuously calling write on a file which is available in Application_2 through the libfuse. So, at certain instance the Application_2 cannot accomodate data and it returns ENOSPC to Application_1. On receiving ENOSPC Application_1 must wait on the file FD to receive POLLOUT. And on receiving the POLLOUT on the file it must resume write().

For this I am using the SELECT() api to wait on the file_fd to receive the POLLOUT. Hence, on ENOSPC I am doing following:

```
           fd_set fdSetWrite;
           FD_ZERO(&fdSetWrite);
           FD_SET(fd_write, &fdSetWrite);
           if (-1 == select(fd_write + 1, NULL, &fdSetWrite,NULL,0))
           {
              printf("\n\t\t error select ");
              close(fd_write);
              exit(0);
           }
           else
              printf("Select is unblocked\n");

           if (FD_ISSET(fd_write, &fdSetWrite))
           {
              printf("Write FD is Set");
           }
```

But what I can see is the select() is getting unblocked immediately. Application_2 is not setting POLLOUT event here. I had blocked that for confirmation. But it is getting unblocked.

Really don't know how this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported mechanism for getting automatically unblocked when space is available on a device. You will have to retry periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes there is no such mechanism to get automatically unblocked on spcae availability. But in my case the APPLICATION_2 actually does this. And the APPLICATION_2 on available space will send a POLLOUT event on the fd_write on which APPLICATION_1 is waiting.
Well that's my plan. 
But here the issue is SELECT is not getting blocked on the APPLICATION_1, it's immediately getting unblocked and the fd_write is getiing set immediately as if something is there on the FD. But APPLICATION_2 is not setting that FD(fd_write) for sure.

Comment: The select is not getting blocked because the lack of space does not make the descriptor unready for writing. That a write will produce an error (such as out of space) doesn't mean the descriptor isn't ready for that write. You can only wait for something that would block.

Comment: My intention is to Block APPLICATION_1 (so that it do not write() anything) unless APPLICATION_2 sends POLLOUT. Sending POLLOUT from APPLICATION_2 is working. But how do I block APPLICATION_1? 
Thanks for the patience though.

Comment: @Shantanu As I said, you can't. There is no way to block until space is available. The descriptor is ready when it could not block and it could not block.

Comment: In my case write() is getting ENOSPC. So, in that condition I am trying to Block it using SELECT(). But it's getting unblocked immediately.

Comment: @Shantanu Right. Because, as I explained, the descriptor is ready for writing now since it will not block. So you cannot wait for space to be available because the descriptor is ready for writing whether or not space is available. If an operation will produce an error, so long as that error is not "would have blocked", the descriptor is ready for that operation and so there is nothing to wait for.